# What's the order of Windows startup?

Tags: windows, authentication, startup, runonce

I'm curious to know the order of Windows startup during a user login. Does anyone know?
Basically, my application was being invoked by login script that a GPO calls. While 3rd party EXE was being invoked, it was failing to start.

Then, through trial and error, I found that HKCU...\RunOnce keys execute after the login script. Same result, the EXE was being called, but failing to start.

What worked: updated the login script create a shortcut in the user's Startup folder. Now the EXE starts up as expected.

I know that AutoRuns can tell me all the locations where startup items can be placed, does anyone know the execution order as a whole? I was able to find that Run and RunOnce keys get called asynchronously. I can keep testing each startup item that AutoRuns states, but this could take days.

I'm mostly interested in Windows 2003 Server login startup flow, but I would suspect its very similar to other Windows flavors in use today.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457123.aspx  Look at the "Logon Phase" section.

Comment: Have a look into "Windows Internals" by Mark E. Russinovich and David A. Solomon. They explain this in great detail.

Comment: Yes, I have one of the latest editions, but I didn't find the page where it listed the order of execution (and I was not skimming over the chapters). Maybe I missed it, would you recall the chapter?

Answer (score 14):

Source: [Understanding the Startup Process - Windows 7 Tutorial](http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/understanding-the-startup-process.html)

> The normal startup sequence for Windows 7 is:
>
> 1. Power-on self test (POST) phase
> 2. Initial startup phase
> 3. Windows Boot Manager phase
> 4. Windows Boot Loader phase
> 5. Kernel loading phase
> 6. Logon phase
>
> [image: a high-level overview of the different paths startup can take]
>
> **Kernel Loading Phase**   The Windows Boot Loader is responsible for loading the Windows kernel (`Ntoskrnl.exe`) and the HAL into memory.
>   Together, the kernel and the HAL initialize a group of software
>   features that are called the Windows executive. The Windows executive
>   processes the configuration information stored in the registry in
>   `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet` and starts services and drivers. The
>   following sections provide more detail about the kernel loading phase.
>
> **Logon Phase**
>
> The Windows subsystem starts `Winlogon.exe`, a system service that
>   enables you to log on and log off. `Winlogon.exe` then does the
>   following:
>
> - Starts the Services subsystem (`Services.exe`), also known as the SCM. The SCM initializes services that the registry entry Start
>     designates as Autoload in the registry subkey
>     `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Servicename`.
> - Starts the Local Security Authority (LSA) process (`Lsass.exe`).
> - Parses the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> key combination at the Begin Logon prompt (if the computer is part of an
>     AD DS domain).
>
> The logon user interface (LogonUI) feature and the credential provider
>   (which can be the standard credential provider or a third-party
>   credential provider) collect the user name and password (or other
>   credentials) and pass this information securely to the LSA for
>   authentication. If the user supplied valid credentials, access is
>   granted by using either the default Kerberos V 5 authentication
>   protocol or Windows NT LAN Manager (NTLM).
>
> Winlogon initializes security and authentication features while PnP
>   initializes auto-load services and drivers. After the user logs on,
>   the control set referenced by the registry entry `LastKnownGood`
>   (located in `HKLM\SYSTEM\Select`) is updated with the contents in the
>   `CurrentControlSet` subkey. By default, Winlogon then starts
>   `Userinit.exe` and the Windows Explorer shell. Userinit may then start
>   other processes, including:
>
> - **Group Policy settings take effect** Group Policy settings that apply to the user and computer take effect.
> - **Startup programs run** When not overridden by Group Policy settings, Windows starts logon scripts, startup programs, and services
>     referenced in the following registry subkeys and file system folders:
>
>   ```
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Runonce
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Run
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Run
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
>   SystemDrive\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
>   SystemDrive\Documents and Settings\username\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
>   ```
>
> Several applications might be configured to start by default after you
>   install Windows, including Windows Defender. Computer manufacturers or
>   IT departments might configure other startup applications.
>
> Windows startup is not complete until a user successfully logs on to
>   the computer. If startup fails during the logon phase, you have a
>   problem with a service or application configured to start
>   automatically.

*If you want further information check the source link.*

Comment: Took me a while to get through this, just as interesting as the Windows Internals book I have. Unfortunately, I'm unable to find the step where it says something like "Step n: Execute user's Startup folder files". As before, I did notice RunOnce ran before the user's Startup folder. Apologies if I missed it from your answer.

Comment: Although credited, this is 100% copy/paste from the given source, and should not by posted as an answer unless explicitly granted by the copyright owner imo. I'd rather post this as a comment with a link to the source.

Comment: From http://sourcedaddy.com/legal/: `(...)You agree not to modify, reproduce, transmit, distribute, discriminate, sell, publish or broadcast any such material or content without the written authorization of SourceDaddy or the appropriate affiliate or licensor.`

Comment: @SteinarLima Yeah, we see that almost everywhere that is quoted as copy-pasta. It's here, it's got two votes, it answers the question and it's the only answer. I just formatted it to look better (you should see how crappy the original answer was). (btw, avoid non-code content in code blocks, even in comments).

Comment: @SteinarLima You'll be surprised to know that SourceDaddy themselves copied this from [Microsoft TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457123.aspx).

Comment: @ADTC Interesting that SourceDaddy have copied the material themselves, but it doesn't change the fact that this answer does not obey the [SO rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing), and thus this answer should be deleted.

Comment: @ADTC Just click the `edited xx mins ago` to see the revision history of an answer/question. And [comments only support](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) `bold, italic, code and links` markdown, so I'll continue to use code markdown for quotes in comments if that is OK with you.

Comment: I have a question, by putting app's shortcut into startup folder, will it auto run after reboot without login to windows?